# Fail to get values from dictionary in ansible playbook

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I'm trying to get some values from a dictionary in ansible playbook.
First, I build the dictionary and it runs correctly.
Then, I would compute the output_dict evaluating the values of this dictionary but I have the issue above.

```
- set_fact:
    state_service: "{{ state_service | default({}) | combine({ item.key : item.value }) }}"
  with_items:
    - { 'key': 'op_state', 'value': "{{Check_Operative_State.results[0].stdout}}"}
    - { 'key': 'ad_state', 'value': "{{Check_Administrative_State.results[0].stdout}}"}

- name: Display the state of service
  debug: msg="{{state_service}}"

- set_fact:
    output_dict: '{{output_dict | default([]) + ["CHECK ERRORS IN SERVICE ************PASSED" if ((item.op_state == "enabled" and item.ad_state == "unlocked") or (item.op_state == "disabled" and item.ad_state == "locked")) else "CHECK ERRORS IN SERVICE **********FAILED"] }}'
  with_items: "{{state_service}}"
```

The error:

```
**************************************************
2022-02-04 19:04:45,341 p=4478 u=abcd n=ansible | ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "ad_state": "unlocked",
        "op_state": "enabled"
    }
}
2022-02-04 19:04:45,366 p=4478 u=abcd n=ansible | TASK [check : set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
2022-02-04 19:04:45,366 p=4478 u=abcd n=ansible | fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'op_state'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/abcd/health/service/script/roles/health/tasks/main.yaml': line 483, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- set_fact:\n  ^ here\n"}
2022-02-04 19:04:45,368 p=4478 u=abcd n=ansible | PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the list below to simplify the example

```yaml
  l1:
    - {key: op_state, value: enabled}
    - {key: ad_state, value: unlocked}
```

Use the filter *items2dict* to create a dictionary from the list, e.g.

```yaml
  state_service: "{{ l1|items2dict }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  state_service:
    ad_state: unlocked
    op_state: enabled
```

You can't iterate a dictionary, but you can use *dict2items* to convert the dictionary to a list, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ state_service|dict2items }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item:
    key: op_state
    value: enabled

  item:
    key: ad_state
    value: unlocked
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir! Another question:

Comment: I would execute a replacement over the items of a list : (my_list | map('regex_replace', 'regularExpression', 'result') | list) . my_list is :["300m","50m","0","4","1050m"] . I want to remove the "m" and divide per 1000 where occurres the "m" at last of the string, and moltiplicate per 1000 in the other cases. Can you help me?

Comment: Iterate this ``"{{ (item is match('.*m'))|ternary(item[:-1]|int / 1000, item|int * 1000) }}"``.

Comment: Open a new question next time.

Comment: Sorry Vladimir! I opened a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71037638/replace-items-in-a-list-ansible-playbook