# Replace items in a list ansible playbook

Tags: regex, dictionary, ansible

I have the following dictionary:

```json
{
  "test1": ["300m","","0","4","1050m"],
  "test2": ["600m","","","0","2"]
}
```

I would execute a replacement over the items of the above lists and tried this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    result: "{{result | default({}) | combine( { item.key: item.value | map((item is match('.*m'))|ternary(item[:-1]|int / 1000, item|int * 1000)) | list} ) }}"
  with_items: "{{dict_ns_cpu | dict2items}}"
  ignore_errors: true
```

With the values of the list:

- If the value ends with `m`, I want to remove it and divide the value per 1000.
- If the value is only a number, multiply per 1000

I get the following error:

> "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{result | default({}) | combine( { item.key: item.value | map((item is match('.*m'))|ternary(item[:-1]|int / 1000, item|int * 1000)) | list} ) }}): unhashable type: 'slice'"

Could anyone help me?

Comment: 300m -> 0.3 , 1050m -> 1.05?   but could you explain when you mutliply by 1000?  give some samples please

Comment: I downvoted because you changed the question. This is the last time I answer your changed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, given the data

```yaml
    dict_ns_cpu:
      test1: ["300m","50m","0","4","1050m"]
      test2: ["600m","400m","10m","0","2"]
```

the task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ result|d({})|combine({item.key: _list|from_yaml}) }}"
      loop: "{{ dict_ns_cpu|dict2items }}"
      vars:
        _list: |-
          {% for i in item.value %}
          {% if i is match('.*m') %}
          - {{ i[:-1]|int / 1000 }}
          {% else %}
          - {{ i|int * 1000 }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
    test1: [0.3, 0.05, 0, 4000, 1.05]
    test2: [0.6, 0.4, 0.01, 0, 2000]
```

---

If you change the data

```yaml
    dict_ns_cpu:
      test1: ["300m","","0","4","1050m"]
      test2: ["600m","","","0","2"]
```

the result will be (ansible [core 2.12.1])

```
  result:
    test1: [0.3, 0, 0, 4000, 1.05]
    test2: [0.6, 0, 0, 0, 2000]
```

---

Use *select* if you want to silently omit empty items. For example, change the line

```yaml
          {% for i in item.value|select %}
```

The result will be

```yaml
  result:
    test1: [0.3, 0, 4000, 1.05]
    test2: [0.6, 0, 2000]
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, you are helping me a lot! I noticed that with the code written by you  above I have an error on a list, for example: ["0", "", "10m", 300m", "4", ""]. The error is : `"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ formatted|d({})|combine({item.key: _list|from_yaml}) }}): a string or stream input is required"` . Maybe another check is required?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. I see the empty string translated to '0'. But, this wasn't part of this question. Was it? Moreover, it's up to you to sanitize your data. I don't know what you want to do with empty items. 1) Omit it silently 2) Replace it with '0' 3) Report error 4) Anything else? Open new question when you decide what you want.

Comment: Opened a new question, I would omit it silently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71048228/replace-items-in-an-heterogeneous-list-ansible-playbook

Comment: This is trivial. Use *select*. For example ``['a', '', 'b']|select`` gives ``['a', 'b']``

Answer (score 1):

If you literally want to replace an 'm' with '000' when the 'm' is preceded by a digit and succeeded by a `"` you could do:

- [`\d(m)"`](https://regex101.com/r/mfXlNw/2)

[image]

Comment: Taking the first list of my dictionary, the result should be [0.3, 0.5, 0, 4000, 1.05]. So, for the first element I removed the "m" and divided 300/1000, same for the second and fifth element,  for the second and third I moltiplicated per 1000.

Comment: Oh I see. In that case @Vladimir's answer is the way to go. A regex approach would be much less capable here.