# Replace items in an heterogeneous list ansible playbook

Tags: regex, dictionary, ansible

I have the following dictionary:

```json
{
  "test1": ["300m","","0","4","1050m"],
  "test2": ["600m","","","0","2"]
}
```

I would execute a replacement over the items of the above lists and tried this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    formatted: "{{ formatted|d({})|combine({item.key: _list|from_yaml}) }}"
  loop: "{{ dict_ns_cpu|dict2items }}"
  vars:
    _list: |-
      {% for i in item.value %}
      {% if i is match('.*m') %}
      - {{ i[:-1]|int / 1000 }}
      {% else %}
      - {{ i|int * 1000 }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

With the values of the list:

- If the value ends with `m`, I want to remove it and divide the value per 1000.
- If the value is only a number, multiply per 1000
- If it is an empty string `""`, omit the element

I get the following error:

> "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ formatted|d({})|combine({item.key: _list|from_yaml}) }}): a string or stream input is required"

My Ansible version is 2.8.1.
Maybe another check is required?

Comment: 'from_yaml' will be expecting a string as its piped input. You're piping the object in, it's already parsed yaml. That's probably not the only problem, but not sure.

Comment: Already, I would strongly recommend you to update your version, as 2.8 end of life was one year ago: https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine

Comment: Downgraded to 2.8.1, still cannot reproduce.

Comment: Could you create a real [mre]? I.e. where does if fail exactly? You have three filters applied in this `set_fact`, which one is causing the issue? If you reduce it to `formatted: "{{ _list|from_yaml }}"` do you still encounter the issue?

Comment: Please do not ask the (virtually almost) same question twice. Edit your original question.